# Cakephp 2.0 starts complaining about mod_rewrite

Tags: cakephp

I run Cakephp 2.0 on Ubuntu 10.04, Mysql, Apache2, PHP5, hosted at linode.com. Just two days ago, when clicking on the link from my homepage www.cross-town-traffic-software.com to freecite, I get the mod_rewrite message from Cakephp. Sometimes I don't. I have check all of my logs and nothing comes up. I checked the sites-available and all of the .htaccess files and they are all inorder, how do I trouble shoot?

Comment: Have you checked the pdo's are installed or not. This issue may also causes some problem during initial setup.

Comment: What's the error? Also, clicking on "freecite" takes me to a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Check for these lines and change as I have done here :

DocumentRoot /var/www/
 
Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride all
 
 
Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride all
 Order allow,deny 
allow from all

Save the file & restart apache :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: What does the tmp folder have to do with mod rewrite? Also there shouldn't be a need for executable permissions on the tmp folder..

Comment: Okay, but this still doesn't have anything to do with the question. Rewrite is enabled and working for sure, as you can tell by visiting http://www.cross-town-traffic-software.com/freecite/users/login

Comment: I had changed the layout from cakegeneric to my own, thats when i got the rewrite message, when switching back to the cakegeneric layout, it went away. Also did all of the above...

Comment: Well, if you don't know how to input a new css in your app, maybe the best way is for you to edit cake.generic.css and use that. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple! cake.generic.css contains the following:

```
/** Elements **/
#url-rewriting-warning {
    display:none;
}
```

So when you remove that file #url-rewriting-warning will be displayed.

Cheers,
Fredrik